# Talend Context variable

Tags: talend

I am a newbie Talend developer, need a help with context variables.  I searched here if there is a solution for similar approach, didnt find it.

In my query I have to use this date range function:

```
Date BETWEEN to_char((add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),-2)),'YYYYMMDD') 
AND to_char(LAST_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM')),'YYYYMMDD')
```

We need to use context variable to take advantage to run different date range during runtime.  Above function, I replaced in the query with `(date between ="+context.daterange+")` and trying to plug these functions to Context - value as tree as below:
`to_char((add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM'),-5)),'YYYYMMDD')'AND'to_char(LAST_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM')),'YYYYMMDD')`,  I get below error:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00905: missing keyword

If I use hard coded value on "Value as tree" context as below then works
"'20150301'and'20150831'"

Trying to replace this with the function. How can I combine that function with `AND`.

My tJavacode has

```
context.DATE = (String)row1.NDate;
```

Can you please help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Date cannot be between two texts. Since your context variables is a String then use `to_date` function:

```
"select ... where my_date between to_date("
+TalendDate.formatDate("ddMMyyyy",TalendDate.addDate(new Date(), 2, "MM"))+
",'DDMMYYYY') and 
+TalendDate.formatDate("ddMMyyyy",TalendDate.addDate(new Date(), 5, "MM"))+
");"
```